# VB.NET Chart to auto scale, but stay with 10x AxisX (Real time chart)

Tags: vb.net, charts

Please excuse me possibly having difficulties explaining this question due to my inexperience with charts in vb.net.

**Intro:**

At a button click (eventually a timer) I use this

```
        Chart1.Series("Channel 1").ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.FastLine
    With Chart1.ChartAreas(0)
        .AxisX.Maximum = 10 'or double.NaN?
        .AxisX.Minimum = 0
        .AxisY.Maximum = 100
        .AxisY.Minimum = 0
        .AxisX.Interval = 1
    End With
```

and adds this

```
Chart1.Series("Channel 1").Points.AddXY(lHrMin.Text, tbCount1.Text) 'A count number and time in hr-min-sec format
Chart1.Series("Channel 2").Points.AddXY(lHrMin.Text, tbcount2.Text) 'A count number and time in hr-min-sec format
```

This results my chart to look like this if I click the button a few times

[image]

**The issue:**

Example above stops at axisx `10` because thats my maximum. `NaN` instead of `10` will result the next image below.

Since its going to be hooked up to a timer, I want my chart to always view the last hour or so, but not more. I don't want it to be long, because then it will be so small, like this:

[image]

**What I want:**

So it should scale forever like a real time chart, but only by always displaying 10 axisX. I found this gif to illustrate what I'm looking for https://camo.githubusercontent.com/19cfad4976e427bf31ca6a0a3d03728cf2b10704/687474703a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f4d524b32304b622e676966 / http://tinyurl.com/jhb62pt - also this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JdwW7UTjO2A

For some reason this doesn't seem to be as easy as I'd want it to be. I've been trying so many things from many different sources, but none really worked.

**My question...**

How can I make the chart stay with 10 axisX, but still make it update at each button click (timer eventually)? Make it loop I suppose... Guessing its probably something as simple as a property or something. Thanks.

**Edit 1:**
I've found a couple of keywords. Real-time chart with plot.
Deleting last value of series and replacing with new. The questions remains, how?

Comment: Maybe you can try removing the oldest dots when you have too much ?

Comment: Yeah I suppose that could be something, but I can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: Isn't there documentation about charts ?

Comment: Well sure there is, but I can't find anything that helps me making it a real-time chart.

Comment: Do you have the link ? If you can find where to remove some points from the chart there you go...

Comment: http://www.advsofteng.com/doc/cdnetdoc/realtimedemo.htm for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say try something like this :

```
'Whenever you need to add a point
Public Sub AddPoint(Channel as String, Time as String, Count as Integer)
  Dim points = Chart1.Series(Channel).Points
  if points.Count > maxPoints then 'Where maxPoints is the maximum number of points you can allow on your chart
    points.removeAt(0) 'Will work if points is an Enumerable
  End if
  points.addXY(Time, Count)
End Sub
```

The idea is to remove the oldest points from the chart, so it will look like it's moving.